# Does a flush beat a straight in three-card poker?

Tags: poker

Does a flush beat a straight in three-card poker?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it doesn't beat it.

Unlike 'normal' Poker, where a flush does beat it, a straight is much less likely with three cards and is ranked higher as a result.

The order of probability (least likely first) is:

1. Straight flush
2. Three of a kind
3. Straight
4. Flush
5. Pair

Comment: With 6. High card, are these the only hands in 3 card poker? Assuming this order doesn't refer to brag which has a prial of 3s as the superior hand.